# Using js in vscode webView when using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vscode-extensions

I want to use a ClassDiagram.js file in inject it as a script of my vscode extension webview

The view html content is being constructed in this way

```js
this.panel.webview.html = this.buildContent();
    
private buildContent(): string {
    let scriptPath = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this.context.extensionPath, 'js')).with({
        scheme: "vscode-resource"
    }).toString() + '/ClassDiagram.js';

    let header: string = `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <script src="${scriptPath}"></script>
        </head>
        <body>`;
    let body: string = '<canvas id="diagramCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>';
    let footer: string = `</body></html>`;
   
    let content = header + body + footer;
   
    return content;
}
```

The above code is an adaptation of this code - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47631

Here is the webpack configuration, that is being used to bundle the extension : ClassDiagram.js is listed as external dependency) but is not being copied to the dist folder

````js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
    target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

    entry: ['./src/extension.ts' ] , // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    output: { // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'extension.js',
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "../[resource-path]",
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: {
        webviewJS: './src/js/ClassDiagram.js',
        vscode: "commonjs vscode" // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    },
    resolve: { // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    compilerOptions: {
                        "module": "es6" // override `tsconfig.json` so that TypeScript emits native JavaScript modules.
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
}

module.exports = config;
```

I have also try to use the example provided by MS without success
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#loading-local-content

So I'm asking how can I use a .js file from a webview when is being bundle with webpack (I dont want to concatenate my js script when building the html)
````

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the webpack configuration here is not relevant

1. Create a `js` folder on the root of your vscode extension
2. Put your `js` file in there in this case `ClassDiagram.js`
3. Use a nonce to allow the script to be fetched and used (see code) - more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce
4. Load the script inside the `<body>` tag - see code

```js
constructor(
    private projectArtifacts: ProjectArtifacts,
    private context: vscode.ExtensionContext
) {
    this.basePath = context.extensionUri.fsPath;
}

private buildContent(): string {
    // Use a nonce to whitelist which scripts can be run
    const nonce = this.getNonce();
    const scriptUri = this.panel.webview.asWebviewUri(
        vscode.Uri.file(path.join(this.basePath, "js", "ClassDiagram.js"))
    );

    let header: string = `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>`;

    let body: string = `<canvas id="diagramCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
        <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>`;

    let footer: string = `</body></html>`;

    let content = header + body + footer;

    return content;
}

getNonce(): string {
    let text = "";
    const possible =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(
            Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)
        );
    }
    return text;
}
```

The result is a webview with and html canvas to do your custom drawings [image]